# Visual Studio (C++) highlighting TODO and compiler errors in the margin with colored marker?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, ide

Is there a way in Visual Studio (2012, C++) to allow the IDE to highlight compiler errors and TODO comments (like how Eclipse shows them- as a colored line near the current file's scrollbar)?

I know there is a window called Task List, but I don't want another window- just the lines "highlighted" near the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced Scrollbar from [Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) shows compiler errors, changes, bookmarks and breakpoints near the scrollbar, but not tasks.